# The last part of a cron task fails, can't work out why

Tags: cron

I've got a problem with cron on my server which i think is down to the environment or user that cron runs under.

My app is set up under a user called `deploy`.  The root folder for the app is `/var/www/apps/akrotoski`, and the executable for the app, which i need to run in this cron task, lives in a subfolder called `bin` and is called `thoth`.

My cron task is thus, created by typing "crontab -e" while logged in as the `deploy` user:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
43 * * * *  echo "time = `date`, USER=$USER, current folder = `pwd`, which thoth = `which thoth`" >> ~/import_times.txt; cd /var/www/apps/akrotoski;  /var/www/apps/akrotoski/bin/thoth --run_command 'ExternalPost.import'
```

At the moment it's set up to run every hour, at 43 minutes past, so i can set it to a time that's just about to happen, then wait for it to kick off.

The first part, with the "echo" is just me trying to debug what's going on.  If i run this on my command line it writes the following into `~/import_times.txt`:

`time = Tue Nov  1 23:43:52 UTC 2011, USER=deploy, current folder = /var/www/apps/akrotoski, which thoth = /var/www/apps/akrotoski/bin/thoth`

and then runs the thoth command (which imports some data off the web).

So, that all seems fine - it's got the right folder, the right user, the right exe.  However, the line written into `~/import_times.txt` by the cron task looks like this:

`time = Tue Nov  1 23:43:01 UTC 2011, USER=, current folder = /home/deploy, which thoth =`

Ie, no user, which would explain in turn why `which thoth` doesn't return anything since it gets the location out of the deploy (or root) user's PATH variable.  Looking in my db, i can see that nothing's been imported, so my "thoth --run_command" call didn't get done properly.

If i create a crontab with "crontab -e", logged in as deploy, doesn't that run under deploy?  Can someone set me straight as to what might be going wrong?

thanks, max

EDIT - for @ott below, who suggested i output the value of set - this is what i got from calling set in cron:

```
HOME='/home/deploy'
IFS='   
'
LOGNAME='deploy'
OPTIND='1'
PATH='/usr/bin:/bin'
PPID='5948'
PS1='$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/home/deploy'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
```

The path is much reduced, but i do pass the full path to the thoth exe in my cron job anyway:

```
cd /var/www/apps/akrotoski; /var/www/apps/akrotoski/bin/thoth --run_command 'ExternalPost.import'
```

Can you see anything missing from `set` which would be required to make this work?

EDIT - i worked out the answer thanks to @ott's help, detailed in the comments below.  It's below the comment fold though so for the sake of anyone else who's browsed to this, the problem was that the environment cron was running in knew about the ruby bin, but it didn't know that it had to open the thoth exe with ruby.  So i just had to add 'ruby' before the thoth exe, with the full path to the ruby bin just to be on the safe side.  I'm still cd'ing to the app folder first, again just to be safe, with all the full paths it might not be necessary:

```
0 * * * *  cd /var/www/apps/akrotoski; /usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/apps/akrotoski/bin/thoth --run_command 'ExternalPost.import'
```

Comment: I believe cron runs with an empty environment (no variables), unless they are specifically set by the script that is running. So either hard code them (e.g. for paths, use absolute paths) or export the variables needed in your script.

Comment: thanks @cyberx86.  I did hardcode the path to the exe (thoth) since i thought that might be the case, but it doesn't seem to run.  I'll try putting some logging inside my app so i can see if it does anythin at all.

Comment: Check (and post relevant parts of) your cron log for clues, and check that the `thoth` program is executable by the `deploy` user.

Comment: Is `thoth` a binary or just a shellscript? If it's binary and you have strace on the system, change your command to `strace -fvo thoth.out /var/www/apps/akrotoski/bin/thoth --run_command 'ExternalPost.import'`. This gives a longer textfile, you could put it to pastebin.com or similar if you don't find the reason by yourself.

Comment: Thanks @ott.  I've given strace a go.  I can't see anything obviously wrong but i'm not sure what it all means.  Here's the strace for the working version, when i call it normally from the command line: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/846812/thoth_working.out, and here's the not-working strace generated by calling it from cron:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/846812/thoth_not_working.out

Comment: It's not loading the shared libs from `/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/`, it's only trying `/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/`. The fastest fix would be (as root) `cd /usr/local/bin ; ln -s ruby/site_ruby site_ruby`. Another way: there must be some variables in your environment with `RUBY-something=/usr/local/...` pointing to the lib-dir. You could also set this in the cron line (`RUBY...=/usr/local/...`), this should help too.

Comment: thanks @ott - did you mean to say `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/usr/local/lib` for the folder to put the link in?  There is a `ruby` executable in `/usr/local/bin` but being an exe it has no site_ruby subdirectory.  I tried linking `site_ruby` to `ruby/site_ruby` in the dir folder but that didn't help.

Comment: Nope, `/usr/local/lib`, /usr/local/bin was a typo, so: `cd /usr/local/lib ; ln -s ruby/site_ruby site_ruby`. Have you something with RUBY in your environment?

Comment: Cracked it - i had to specify the ruby executable as well.  There's no shebang at the top of the exe to tell it to use ruby, that must be why it didn't work, i'm guessing?  So, my final working crontab has `0 * * * *  cd /var/www/apps/akrotoski; /usr/local/bin/ruby /var/www/apps/akrotoski/bin/thoth --run_command 'ExternalPost.import'`.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: btw @ott if you want to put this in an answer i'll tick it :)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your command to see the environment like this:

```
( set ; echo "time = `date`, USER=$USER, current folder = `pwd`, which thoth = `which thoth`" ) >> ~/import_times.txt
```

You'll notice a very reduced environment and PATH. You could extract the username from the HOME variable.